# How to open a Java src repo in Eclipse (and later build it)

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build

I am working with `swingx-ws` for Java.  The source code can be found here:

http://java.net/downloads/swingx-ws/releases/1.0/swingx-ws-1.0-src.zip

The project is unmaintained, and the package contains a few out of date dependencies.  Following advice from [HERE](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/javadesktop/java-desktop-technologies/swinglabs/swingx-164-released#comment-824759), I'd like to (1) open this source in Eclipse, (2) clean up the dependencies ("organize imports" per that post, which I'm hoping/assuming Eclipse can do automagically somehow), and then (3) build a JAR file out of it all.

However, I cannot even seem to get past the first step (getting it open in Eclipse).  I've tried "import existing projects into workspace" and "new Java project from existing Ant buildfile," but neither seem to work.

EDIT: Here is exactly what I've done with the Ant `build.xml`:  I added the following line near the end of the `project` element (since my first errors were related to missing javac element):

```
<javac executable="C:\eclipse\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\javac.exe"></javac>
```

However, now I get a new (and very vague) error, simply: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Please post the stack trace around your error.  You are right, the NullPointerException is too vague, but seeing what code is running before the exception might point people towards a helpful suggestion.

Comment: @RichardNeish I'm getting the error as a popup by itself (part of the "java project from ant buildfile" dialog), not in the console window where it usually shows stack traces.  So I don't even know what the stack looks like.